# Run a maven project in eclipse using "Run on Server" using the already configured server on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have lately started using maven as a build tool. I integrated it with eclipse using `maven-plugin-for-eclipse`. But I have few issues and questions related to that

- How would I use the tomcat server which is already configured in eclipse. I mean how should I use `"Run on server"` option on eclipse. If I use `eclipse:run` as you might suggest me, I am unable to configure the server.xml.
- When I put `servlet-api` dependency in `pom.xml`. At the time of build, there is some binding exception due to which i need to remove the dependency from pom.xml. So it is like-  `while writing code, i have to put servlet-api dependency in pom.xml but before i need to run, i have to remove it.` There must be some sort of solution to it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to configure any additional steps to run a maven project using Tomcat. Just right click on your project folder in eclipse and choose "Run on Server" and select Tomcat in the next window. If there is no option like "Run on server" available, go to run configuration and choose Tomcat, then click on Run . This have worked for maven projects which I have generated from App-fuse..

Comment: When i use "Run on server", it doesn't compile the code. and it doesnt even take the compiled code generated through mvn:compile

Comment: Look at the last line of my answer, that option works for me for projects which I've created using App-Fuse.